# Why mobx observable is undefined in recursive component？

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I write a recursive component `TreeNode` like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Icon, Colors } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { FLEX_EXPANDER } from "@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/common/classes";

@withRouter
@inject("store")
@observer
class TreeNode extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.id,
        name: this.props.name,
        level: this.props.level,
        child: this.props.child,
        isShow: true
    };

    leftClickTreeLine() {
        this.setState((prev, next) => ({
            isShow: !this.state.isShow,
        }));

    }

    render() {
        let treeLineStyle = {
            paddingLeft: this.state.level * 15 + "px",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            // backgroundColor:
            //  this.state.currentId === this.state.id ? "#ced9e0" : "#e1e8ed",
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <p
                    className="treeLine"
                    style={treeLineStyle}
                    onClick={() => this.leftClickTreeLine()}
                >
                    <Icon
                        icon={
                            this.state.child.length > 0
                                ? this.state.isShow
                                    ? "chevron-down"
                                    : "chevron-right"
                                : "folder-open"
                        }
                        iconSize={12}
                        color={Colors.GRAY2}
                        style={{ marginRight: 10 + "px" }}
                    ></Icon>
                    {this.state.name}
                </p>
                <ul
                    style={{
                        height: this.state.isShow ? "auto" : 0 + "px",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                    }}
                >
                    {this.state.child.length > 0 &&
                        this.state.child.map((i, k) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={i.id}>
                                    <TreeNode
                                        {...i}
                                    />
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TreeNode;
```

This level `TreeNode` can get `this.props.store.clickId`, but the children can't, why?

Answer (score 0):

```js
{this.state.child.length > 0 &&
                        this.state.child.map((i, k) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={i.id}>
                                    <TreeNode
                                        {...i}
                                        store={this.props.store} //add store here
                                    />
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
```